# How do you resize or set the height and width of a Font Awesome 5 SVG?

Tags: svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

How do you resize or set the height and width of a Font Awesome 5 SVG? For example why

```
<path d="m25 43.5000536c0-1.354163.4947901-2.5260352 1.4843715-3.5156166.9895813-.9895813 2.1614535-1.4843714 3.5156166-1.4843714h7.4999821v24.9999404h-7.4999821c-1.3541631 0-2.5260353-.4947901-3.5156166-1.4843715-.9895814-.9895814-1.4843715-2.1614536-1.4843715-3.5156166zm44.9998927-4.999988c1.3541631 0 2.5260353.4947901 3.5156166 1.4843714.9895814.9895814 1.4843715 2.1614536 1.4843715 3.5156166v14.9999643c0 1.354163-.4947901 2.5260352-1.4843715 3.5156166-.9895813.9895814-2.1614535 1.4843715-3.5156166 1.4843715h-7.4999821v-24.9999404zm-29.9999285 24.9999404v-24.9999404h19.9999524v24.9999404zm13.7499673-18.1249568c-.5208325 0-.963539.1822908-1.3281219.5468737-.3645828.3645828-.5468737.8072893-.5468737 1.3281218s.1822909.963539.5468737 1.3281218c.3645829.3645829.8072894.5468737 1.3281219.5468737.5208324 0 .9635389-.1822908 1.3281218-.5468737.3645828-.3645828.5468737-.8072893.5468737-1.3281218s-.1822909-.963539-.5468737-1.3281218c-.3645829-.3645829-.8072894-.5468737-1.3281218-.5468737zm0 7.4999821c-.5208325 0-.963539.1822908-1.3281219.5468737-.3645828.3645829-.5468737.8072893-.5468737 1.3281218s.1822909.963539.5468737 1.3281219c.3645829.3645828.8072894.5468737 1.3281219.5468737.5208324 0 .9635389-.1822909 1.3281218-.5468737.3645828-.3645829.5468737-.8072894.5468737-1.3281219s-.1822909-.9635389-.5468737-1.3281218c-.3645829-.3645829-.8072894-.5468737-1.3281218-.5468737zm-7.4999822-7.4999821c-.5208325 0-.9635389.1822908-1.3281218.5468737-.3645829.3645828-.5468737.8072893-.5468737 1.3281218s.1822908.963539.5468737 1.3281218c.3645829.3645829.8072893.5468737 1.3281218.5468737s.963539-.1822908 1.3281219-.5468737c.3645828-.3645828.5468737-.8072893.5468737-1.3281218s-.1822909-.963539-.5468737-1.3281218c-.3645829-.3645829-.8072894-.5468737-1.3281219-.5468737zm0 7.4999821c-.5208325 0-.9635389.1822908-1.3281218.5468737s-.5468737.8072893-.5468737 1.3281218.1822908.963539.5468737 1.3281219c.3645829.3645828.8072893.5468737 1.3281218.5468737s.963539-.1822909 1.3281219-.5468737c.3645828-.3645829.5468737-.8072894.5468737-1.3281219s-.1822909-.9635389-.5468737-1.3281218c-.3645829-.3645829-.8072894-.5468737-1.3281219-.5468737z" opacity=".25" />
```

is smaller than,

```
<path d="M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7 8.5-28.6 53 0 89.4-10.1 89.4-64.4 0-61-77.1-89.6-116.9-44.6-23.5 26.4-17.6 42.1-17.6 157.6 50.7 31 118.3 22 160.4-20.1 24.8-24.8 38.5-58 38.5-93 0-35.2-13.8-68.2-38.8-93.3-24.8-24.8-57.8-38.5-93.3-38.5s-68.8 13.8-93.5 38.5c-.3.3-16 16.5-21.2 23.9l-.5.6c-3.3 4.7-6.3 9.1-20.1 6.1-6.9-1.7-14.3-5.8-14.3-11.8V20c0-5 3.9-10.5 10.5-10.5h241.3c8.3 0 8.3 11.6 8.3 15.1 0 3.9 0 15.1-8.3 15.1H130.3v132.9h.3c104.2-109.8 282.8-36 282.8 108.9 0 178.1-244.8 220.3-310.1 62.8zm63.3-260.8c-.5 4.2 4.6 24.5 14.6 20.6C306 56.6 384 144.5 390.6 144.5c4.8 0 22.8-15.3 14.3-22.8-93.2-89-234.5-57-238.3-38.2zM393 414.7C283 524.6 94 475.5 61 310.5c0-12.2-30.4-7.4-28.9 3.3 24 173.4 246 256.9 381.6 121.3 6.9-7.8-12.6-28.4-20.7-20.4zM213.6 306.6c0 4 4.3 7.3 5.5 8.5 3 3 6.1 4.4 8.5 4.4 3.8 0 2.6.2 22.3-19.5 19.6 19.3 19.1 19.5 22.3 19.5 5.4 0 18.5-10.4 10.7-18.2L265.6 284l18.2-18.2c6.3-6.8-10.1-21.8-16.2-15.7L249.7 268c-18.6-18.8-18.4-19.5-21.5-19.5-5 0-18 11.7-12.4 17.3L234 284c-18.1 17.9-20.4 19.2-20.4 22.6z"></path>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add a scale transform.

Comment: @RobertLongson please give an example, also any way to do it using path tag?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform